# Divide data into n groups distributed by some numeric property

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Say I have the following sample of data.

```
[
  { _id: "1", weight: 3 },
  { _id: "2", weight: 3 },
  { _id: "3", weight: 4 },
  { _id: "4", weight: 1.5 }
]
```

I want to take this data, and divide it by the property `weight` such that it is as closely balanced by that property in each group. In this case, the final result should be something like:

```
groupByProperty(fakeData, 2, 'weight');
[
  [{ _id: "1", weight: 3}, { _id: "2", weight: 3}], // total: 6
  [{ _id: "3", weight: 4}, {_id: "4", weight: 1.5}] // total: 5.5
]
```

That is to say, the weight should be as similar/homogenous as possible in each group. Is there an easy way to do this? I have toyed around with some lodash to get it done

```
groupByProperty = function (data, divisions, property) {
  let compartments = _.range(divisions);
  _.each(fakeData, (d) => {
    _(compartments)
      .sortBy((i) => _.sum(_.pluck(i, 'weight')))
      .reverse()
      .first()
      .push(product);
  });
  return compartments;
}
```

Doesn't really work but it's a start.

How can you divide data into n groups distributed by a property in javascript?

Comment: What "doesn't really work" about your proposed solution? This is a [partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) problem and there should be algorithms out there that you can adapt to your needs.

Comment: Did you try to solve problem with trees data structures? I think you problem not in lowdash, you main problem to create right algoritm and write code on JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function:

```
function groupByProperty(data, divisions, field) {
    divisions = Math.round(divisions);
    var l = data.length;

    if(divisions <= 0 || l < divisions) {
        return data;
    } else {
        var out = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < divisions; i++){
            out.push([]);
        }

        data = _.sortBy(data, function(p){return -p[field];});

        for(var i = 0; i < l; i++){
            var record = data[i];

            out = _.sortBy(out, function(p){return _.reduce(p, function(memo, x){return memo + x[field];}, 0);});

            out[0].push(record);
        }
        return out;
    }
};
```

Function for test:

```
var result = groupByProperty(data, 2, 'weight');
console.log(result);
for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
    console.log(_.reduce(result[i], function(memo, p){ return memo + p.weight;}, 0));
}
```

Result for 2, 3, 4 divisions:

```
5.5, 6
```

```
4.5, 3, 4
```

```
1.5, 3, 3, 4
```

Used: [`_.sortBy()`](http://underscorejs.ru/#sortBy) & [`_.reduce()`](http://underscorejs.ru/#reduce)
[Original article on Russian (for php)](http://ziscod.com/partition-problem-na-php/)